# Tomcat6 permissions?

Tags: java, tomcat

Just got my tomcat server working online and trying out a few tutorials, I'm getting this error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission http.strictPostRedirect read)
```

When working with this tutorial:

```
http://www.frank-buss.de/echoservlet/index.html
```

Could someone advise me in simple terms what needs to be done to rectify this?

TIA

Comment: How exactly are you running Tomcat? Are you using the provided shell scripts, are you embedding it in your own code, etc.?

Comment: What does the servlet do when you access it independently of the applet, per the instructions, with http://localhost:8080/echo/index.html   If it works, I suspect then that maybe you're not loading the applet from the server (it has to come from the server in order to access that server), or something of that nature.

Comment: The tomcat is running on a remote linux server. I get the GUI interface but when I send the echo message I get the above error in return. All the files are on the server in the same folder.

Comment: Is this error on the client or server? Also, please post the entire Exception trace, and which browser and servlet engine (with versions) that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salaam,

Try using this context definition

```
<Context path="/echo" docBase="echo" reloadable="true" privileged="true" />
```

else, you may have to setup [tomcat security manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html) :s